# Find orthogonal complement of a (closed) subspace of $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have $\Omega = (-11,11)$ contained in $\mathbb R$ and $I= (2,3)$ contained in $\mathbb R$ too. Then I have $M= \{f \in L^2(\Omega): -f(x)= f(-x^2-2) \text{ for a.e. }x \in I \}$ closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$. Find $M^\bot$.

I know that $M^\bot = \{ g \in L^2(\Omega): \int_{-11}^{11} f(x) g(x)dx=0 , \forall f \in M$}, but I dont understand how to built and then solve the integral since i have the function defined only for the subinterval I

Comment: The definition of $M$ is for $x \in I$, but that doesn't mean $-x^2-2 \in I$. It might help you to think about how you can define a function on $[0,2\pi)$ and then extend it to $\mathbb{R}$ by periodicity: $f(x) = f(x-2n\pi)$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Based on that condition, your integral should split into a few different pieces:

$$\int_{-11}^{11} f(x) g(x)\,dx = \int_{-11}^2 f(x) g(x)\,dx + \int_2^3 f(x)g(x)\,dx + \int_3^{11} f(x)g(x)\,dx.$$

Then you can use your condition to rephrase the middle part. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @CameronWilliams well not really...i would have $\int_{2}^{3} -f(-x^2-2)g(x)dx $, but , i dont know how to proceed, also withe the other part of the integral in order to arrive to a form that allows me to find $M\bot$